# How to make an exact copy of a numpy array (including strides)

Tags: python, numpy

How can I copy a numpy array such that it has identical memory layout to the original array, including strides and any associated discontiguity? Basically, the new `__array_interface__` should be identical except for the pointer.

Rationale: I need to test my code against discontiguous arrays, I need to run multiple destructive tests, hence the need for a copy that preserves discontiguity.

Example (note that copying changes the strides):

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.empty((10, 6))
>>> b = a[::2]
>>> b.strides
(96, 8)
>>> b.copy(order='K').strides
(48, 8)
```

**Edit:**

Here is the complete function I am using based on senderle's answer:

```
def exact_copy(data):
    if data.base is None:
        return data.copy()        
    base = data.base.copy()
    offset = (data.__array_interface__['data'][0] -
              data.base.__array_interface__['data'][0])
    return np.ndarray(buffer=base.data, shape=data.shape, strides=data.strides,
                      offset=offset, dtype=data.dtype)
```

Comment: Does `.copy()` work?  If not, when it is wrong?

Comment: `copy` realigns the data as a contiguous, c-ordered array (in other words, it does not preserve the existing memory layout).

Comment: How about `order='K'`?

Comment: I'm afraid we're going to have to annoy you with questions about why you want this. I can think of at least one way to do it but it feels wrong...

Comment: I only want it for testing--I need to make sure my code correctly handles non-contiguous arrays, and I also need to perform multiple destructive tests on the arrays, hence the need to copy with exact memory structure.

Comment: I would suggest incorporating those details into your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, you can do this, but you probably shouldn't in most cases -- the benefits are not that huge, and a lot of things in `numpy` are harder with non-contiguous data.

Still, it's not hard to do what you want -- you can use the `strides` argument exposed by `ndarray`. Say we start with an array that has some tasty apples inside, but a lot of other cruft. How do we get the apples out?

```
>>> xapplesx = numpy.array(list('xxxaxpxpxlxexsxxx'))
>>> xapplesx
array(['x', 'x', 'x', 'a', 'x', 'p', 'x', 'p', 'x', 'l', 'x', 'e', 'x',
       's', 'x', 'x', 'x'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

We want to start at index `3`, and we want to take every other value and put it in a one-dimensional view, which means we want to take every `2`nd value.

So we pass `offset=3` and `strides=(2,)`:

```
>>> apples = numpy.ndarray(shape=(6,), dtype='|S1', 
                           buffer=xapplesx, offset=3, strides=(2,))
>>> apples
array(['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's'], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

Getting used to using `strides` directly this way takes a bit of careful thinking. Suppose we want to get our apples and put them over `x`s. Now we want a two-dimensional array, and we have to specify strides for both dimensions. But we want the second row of data to contain the values that come right after the apples. So we specify a stride of just `1` for that dimension:

```
>>> applesoverx = numpy.ndarray(shape=(2, 6), dtype='|S1', 
                                buffer=xapplesx, offset=3, strides=(1, 2))
>>> applesoverx
array([['a', 'p', 'p', 'l', 'e', 's'],
       ['x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x', 'x']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

If you're having trouble getting the correct `buffer` data, you can probably do something like this:

```
>>> a = np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)[::-1,:]
>>> x = np.ndarray(shape=a.shape, buffer=a.base.data, 
                   strides=a.strides, offset=72, dtype=a.dtype)
```

The only trick is that you have to work out the correct offset. The result is (I'm pretty sure) a perfect clone:

```
>>> x
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2]])
>>> a
array([[ 9, 10, 11],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 0,  1,  2]])
>>> x.shape
(4, 3)
>>> a.shape
(4, 3)
>>> x.strides
(-24, 8)
>>> a.strides
(-24, 8)
>>> id(x.base)
140602344736320
>>> id(a.base)
140602344736320
```

If you want to make a copy of the original data, you can use `a.base.copy().data` as your `buffer` argument. And (as Luke pointed out), you can determine the offset (see above) with this:

```
a.__array_interface__['data'][0] - a.base.__array_interface__['data'][0]
```

This gives you a reference to the pointer at which the buffer begins for the given array, as documented [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.0/reference/arrays.interface.html).

Comment: A case that may be impossible to clone is ` np.arange(12).reshape(4,3)[::-1,:]`.  Strides is `(-4,16)`, and the buffer is non-contiguous.

Comment: @hpaulj, true, but I think that's just because `numpy` won't give you the buffer data for slices. If you get the original buffer used to create the slice (via `a.base`), you can duplicate the slice with explicit strides, and the result will be clone-able.

Comment: This gets us close, but the memory has not actually been copied (the new array points to the same location in memory).

Comment: @Luke, it's trivial to copy the base though -- `a.base.copy().data`. Is that what you're looking for? Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yeah! Last thing I needed was to calculate the offset like `a.__array_interface__['data'][0] - a.base.__array_interface__['data'][0]`. Mind adding that to your answer?

Comment: @Luke sure, no problem.